# How fire an event from child component to parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular

### parent.component.ts

```
public test(){
 //some code.....
}
```

### parent.component.html

```
<app-child (eventfire)="test($event)"></app-child>
```

- In this part button show child component button show the parent component. But i already show the button on grid. now thre are two buttons. Grid button is not working but newly show button working correctly.

### cild.componen.ts

```
  @Output() eventfire= new EventEmitter<string>();

  calltoParent(): void {
    debugger;
    this.eventfire.next();
  }
```

### child.component.html

```
<button mat-raised-button (click) = calltoParent($event);>Click Here<button>//This already show in grid
```

[image]

- What i want to do is when i click the child componet button want to execute parent **test()** function.
- But **<app-child (eventfire)="test($event)">** when i use this part home component show another **Click here** button. But i dont want to show a another button. Because **child.component.html** button i already show in a grid
- Now i want to after click that button want to  execute parent **test()** how to fix this?

Comment: `this.eventfire.next();` It should be `this.eventfire.emit();`

Comment: Thanks but still not resolved my problem!

Comment: what is your exact scenario, is event is not generated or your showing two click here buttons..?

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem statement. It will be helpful if you can show screenshot of your UI.

Comment: @Kevin_Mac, your code works, check if you has a typo error, see a simple example in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mvj4r7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: event is working correctly newly shown button. not grid button. That mean child component button show in home component because of <app-child (eventfire)="test($event)"></app-child> this part.

Comment: If you want has no button, You can use `this.eventfire.next();`  in a click of the grid, or in ngOnInit or using a Timer... Really I don't know what do you want to achieve

Comment: @Kevin_Mac what is grid button ? what is newly created button ? we don't know. may be restructure your question properly if you want help

Comment: Add a picture. left coner button is newly shown. right side button is grid button. both are same button (<button mat-raised-button (click) = calltoParent($event);>Click Here<button>)

Comment: show us your `parent.html` why there are two buttons ?

Comment: FYI , if you want to trigger event when something happens on child component, the child component should exists in the dom.

Comment: @programoholic because of this parat (<button mat-raised-button (click) = calltoParent($event);>) if i remove that left coner button will be removed. But grid button is not remove. because i and it another way i didnt put that code there is a big code an lot of compnent

Comment: @Kevin_Mac then remove the button from parent. If the event get triggered from child component , why the button is on parent component

Comment: No button in parent component. but child component only contain button. So when i use
<button mat-raised-button (click) = calltoParent($event);>Click Here<button>
in parent component child component button showing in the parent compnent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `output` and `EventEmitter`. Update below code :

in `parent.component.html` , add child selector with the event it fires :

```
<app-child (clicked)="test()"></app-child>
```

in `parent.component.ts` add the `test` method :

```
test(){
    alert('parent function called from child!')
  }
```

now in `child.component.ts` add below code :

```
@Output() clicked = new EventEmitter();

callParent(){
     this.clicked.emit()
  }
```

trigger the `callParent` method when you click the button :

```
  <button (click)="callParent()"> click </button>
```

Here is the working example :  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7lubfo?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)